# How do I create a menu on android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

my answer may be very simple to many of you great coders. I'm in middle school; I just started to code java. my teacher assigned me a project to make an application that takes input from the user using text fields and for data to be saved and to create new files and load old files. Can anyone assist me ,please?

```
package com.example.alex_theguitarboy.phonerepov02;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
        EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();

       switch(id)
        {
            case R.id.menu_save:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Successfullly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

            case R.id.menu_load:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loaded Successfullly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                break;

            case R.id.menu_new:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New file created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}




<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.alex_theguitarboy.phonerepov02.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Menu"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_save"
            android:title="Save"
            android:icon="@drawable/save_icon"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_load"
            android:title="Load"
            android:icon="@drawable/load_icon"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_new"
            android:title="New Game"
            android:icon="@drawable/new_game_icon"
            />
    </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: at least try, how will you ever make it in the industry if you can't even try first, show us your broken code :)

Comment: I uploaded the broken code @ZebRawnsley